# Is python different from java if the scope of the variable inside a method is concerned?

Tags: java, python

I am writing the following code :

```
class NewList():

    def __init__(self,initial_state):
        self.data = initial_state

    def append(self,new_item):
        self.data = self.data + [new_item]
        self.big = self.data

    def deppend(self,new_item):
        self.data = self.data + [new_item]
        self.big = self.big + [new_item]


    my_list = NewList([1,2,3,4,5])
    print(my_list.data)
    my_list.append(6)
    print(my_list.data)
    print(my_list.big)
    my_list.deppend(7)
    print(my_list.data)
    print(my_list.big)
```

I don't think variables such as data,big etc that are declared inside a method can be used in another method in Java. But, here in python we are easily able to use them. Is it that the variables declared inside a method in python have a global scope rather than java that has a local scope ??

Comment: Member variables aren't "declared" at all in Python. The word doesn't make sense.

Comment: Note that `self.big` and `self.data` are attributes, not local variables.

Comment: what do you think the `self` means?

Answer (score 0):

The variable you have defined are declared using `self` keyword. Think of it as `this` in java.

So when you do `self.big = self.data` The big becomes the attribute of the object. Hence it is accessible with the object.

`obj.attribute` and `self.attribute` are essentially the same. And in python, you can create new attributes at fly.